# What is the expression to access User's Contact record fields in Visualforce?

Tags: visualforce, customer-portal, contact

What is the expression to access User's Contact record fields in Visualforce? I need in for Customer Portal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the Contact record in your controller by using the [UserInfo](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_userinfo.htm) object and something along the lines of the following query.  Then you can reference it in your Visualforce page.

```
public class YourController {
    public Contact userContact { get; set; }

    public YourController() {
        userContact = [
            Select Id, Name /*etc.,*/
            From Contact
            Where Id In (Select ContactId
                         From User
                         Where Id = :UserInfo.getUserId())
        ];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_user.htm

After quick look I believe `{!$User.Contact.Email}` etc should be ok.

Comment: `{!$User.ContactId}` is working but `{!$User.Contact.Email}` is not working. Do you know any workarounds?

Comment: Uh, that's a bad news. Try making a formula on User that'd reference the Contact's field? I suspect it won't work either though... Looks like you'll need an apex controller then or maybe some workflow/trigger that'd copy data over when source (Contact) changes.